# Disable Checkbutton with if condition

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI in which contains combobox and checkbutton. 
I want the checkbutton to 
be disabled (gey out) when a specific combobox option is selected.

Following is my code: ( Here I am trying to disable the checkbox1 if the combobox value is 0)

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

root=tk.Tk()
combo=ttk.Combobox(root,values=['0','1','2'])
combo.set("Select No")
combo.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.4)

var1=IntVar()
check1=tk.Checkbutton(root,text="Select1", variable=var1)
check1.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.6)

var2=IntVar()
check2=tk.Checkbutton(root,text="Select2", variable=var2)
check2.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.6)

if combo.get()=='0':
    check1.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ComboboxSelected` event bind as follows:

```
def disable(event):
    if combo.get()=='0':
        check1.config(state = tk.DISABLED)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", disable)
```

The callback function `disable` is invoked each time the value of the `Combobox` is changed

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just had to add `else` condition to make the checkbutton normal.

Comment: Could you have a look at another problem I am having at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063559/disable-some-options-from-tkiner-combobox-with-if-condition