# Disable some options from Tkiner combobox with if condition

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple gui, which has 2 `comboboxes` (say `combo1` and `combo2`).

I want some values of `combo1` to be disabled/deactivated when some specific values of `combo2` are selected.

The following is a sample code:

```
import ttk


root=tk.Tk()
c1_val=['0','1','2','3']
c2_val=['a','b','c']

combo1=ttk.Combobox(root,values=c1_val)
combo1.set("Select No")
combo1.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.4)

combo2=ttk.Combobox(root,values=c2_val)
combo2.set("Select No")
combo2.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.5)




var1=IntVar()
check1=tk.Checkbutton(root,text="Select1", variable=var1)
check1.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.7)

var2=IntVar()
check2=tk.Checkbutton(root,text="Select2", variable=var2)
check2.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.7)



root.mainloop()
```

In the above script, I want the values of `combo1 = ['0','1']`  if  `combo2= ['a']`.

What function can I make here to achieve that?

Comment: Add a callback `command=` to `combo2`, on selection do `combo1.configure(value=['0','1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is an example to `set` the value of a `Combobox`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def setValue(event):
     print(combo.set('January'))

app = tk.Tk() 
app.geometry('400x100')

labelTop = tk.Label(app,
                    text = "Choose your favourite month")
labelTop.grid(column=0, row=0)

combo = ttk.Combobox(app, 
                            values=[
                                    "January", 
                                    "February",
                                    "March",
                                    "April",
                                    "May"])


combo.grid(column=0, row=1)
combo.current(1)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", setValue)
app.mainloop()
```

Apply this logic to your code and it should work

**UPDATE**

To re-assign the values of a particular `Combobox`, try the following:
(Using the same example as above)

```
def setValue(event):
    if combo.get()=='February':
        combo['values'] = ['January', 'May']
    else:
        combo['values'] = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']
```

Comment: That worked fine, but what if I want two values of combobox to be fixed i.e. "January" and "May"?

Comment: please define 'fixed'. do you want both of them displayed?

Comment: Yes, I want the combo of both to be displayed. User can select any one of those

Comment: let me get it correct - when you say that you want the user to select only 1 of the 2, do you mean that the values available in `combo` be just limited to 'January' and 'May'?

Comment: There are two comboxes, if user selects a specific value from combo1, then the value list of combo2 should show only some values i.e. 'January' and 'May'

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it solves your query